# Prove that $ f(z)=z^p-x $ is an irreducible polynomial over the fraction field $ \mathbb{Z}_p(x) $ where $ p $ is a prime number.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $ f(z)=z^p-x $ is an irreducible polynomial over the fraction field $ \mathbb{Z}_p(x) $ where $ p $ is a prime number and $ z $ is an indeterminate over the field $ \mathbb{Z}_p(x) $.

A little help here? I get stuck in this.

Comment: Is $z$ an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$? If this is the case, then $z^p\equiv_p z$, so you should consider $\mathbb{Z}_p(x)/(z-x)$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout No, $ z $ is not an element of $ \mathbb{Z}_p $. $ z $ is an indeterminate over the fraction field $ \mathbb{Z}_p(x) $.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, are you looking at the ring $$\mathbb{Z}_p(x)[z]=\left \{\frac{p(x,z)}{q(x)}\mid p(x,z)\in\mathbb{Z}_p [x,z], 0\neq q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]\right \}$$ ? Or $\mathbb{Z}_p (x,z)$?

Comment: If your $\Bbb{Z}_p=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, then you can use Eisenstein's criterion with the irreducible element $x$ of the polynomial ring $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ in the role of a prime. In other words, the same proof that $z^p-2$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[z]$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout The first one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Eisenstein's criterion requires $ x $ to be a prime element in the coefficient domain $ \mathbb{Z}_p $, but here $ x $ is a unit in the field $ \mathbb{Z}_p(x) $ so it is not a prime element and Eisenstein's criterion fails?

Comment: Eisenstein does work. You have the wrong domain. Use $D=\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. Certainly $x$ is an irreducible polynomial, and the coefficients of $z^p-x\in D[z]$ meet the Eisenstein's criteria. Then you need the counterpart of Gauss' Lemma to conclude that irreducibility over $D$ implies irreducibility over its field of fractions $Q_D$. Here $Q_D=\Bbb{Z}_p(x)$, just what the doctor orderer!

Comment: [Generalized Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Fantastic!! I forgot to use the Gauss' Lemma. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jyrki Lahtonen showed, consider the polynomial $ z^p-x $ in $ (\mathbb{Z}_p[x])[z] $. Since $ x $ is a prime element in the integral domain $ \mathbb{Z}_p[x] $, then by Eisenstein's criterion, $ z^p-x $ is an irreducible polynomial over $ \mathbb{Z}_p[x] $. Furthermore, by Gauss' Lemma, $ z^p-x $ is also an irreducible polynomial over the fraction field $ \mathbb{Z}_p(x) $.

Answer (score 0):

By $\mathbf{Z}_p$ I hope you mean the integers mod $p$, commonly written $\mathbf{Z}/p$ or $\mathbf{F}_p$ nowadays, and not the $p$-adic integers.

Unfortunately, I cannot yet comment to figure out what you mean. Regardless, we can do this with simple casework. (The argument is exactly the same, but I named the variables differently just because.)

---

**Case 1: You meant the integers mod $p$**

Let $k=\mathbf{F}_p(x)$. Consider the splitting field $L$ of $f(z)=z^p-x$ over $k$. Let $g$ be a primitive $p$th root of unity for $\mathbf{F}_p$. Then the roots of $f(z)$ here are $g^k x^{1/p}$ for each $0\le k < p$, in the field $L=k(g, x^{1/p})$.

In a certain sense, the reason why the integers mod $p$ are so nice to work in is the fact that $g$ exists *in $\mathbf{F}_p$*. That is, $L=k(x^{1/p})=\mathbf{F}_p(x^{1/p})$. Note that this field is isomorphic to $k$ via the map $x^{1/p}\mapsto x$. Thus, any ring homomorphism $\varphi:L\to M$ is completely determined by the image of $x^{1/p}$, and the maps $\varphi(x^{1/p})=\alpha$ for $\alpha\ne 0$ are all ring homomorphisms.

To show $f$ is irreducible, it suffices to show that the Galois group $G(L/k)$ acts transitively on the roots of $f(z)$, meaning that for any roots $\alpha, \alpha'$, we can always find an automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ fixing $K$ and sending $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha'$.

(If you don't know Galois theory, the intuition here is that invertible homomorphisms $\sigma:L\to L$ that fix $k$ will fix the coefficients of polynomials $q(z)$ in $k[z]$. Hence, if $\sigma\circ q = q\circ \sigma$, so if $\alpha$ is a root of $q$, then so is $\sigma(\alpha)$. In particular, we know that $f$ has no double roots, so if we could break up $f(z)=q(z)r(z)$, then we would not be able to send any of the roots of $q$ to any of the roots of $r$.)

So pick two roots of $f(z)$, say, $g^jx^{1/p}$ and $g^k x^{1/p}$. Let $\sigma$ be the homomorphism determined by $\sigma(x^{1/p})=g^{k-j}x^{1/p}$. Then $\sigma$ is clearly injective and surjective, so it is an automorphism. Furthermore, since $\sigma(x)=x$, $\sigma$ fixes $k$, so it is an automorphism of $L/k$. Finally, $\sigma(g^jx^{1/p}) = g^{k}x^{1/p}$, as desired.

So $G(L/k)$ indeed acts transitively, and thus $f(z)$ is irreducible.

---

**Case 2: You meant the $p$-adic integers for $p>2$**

Let $k=\mathbf{Z}_p(x)$. Consider the splitting field $L$ of $f(z)=z^p-x$ over $k$. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $p$th root of unity for $\mathbf{Z}_p$. Then the roots of $f(z)$ here are $\zeta^k x^{1/p}$ for each $0\le k < p$, in the field $L=k(\zeta, x^{1/p})$.

In a certain sense, the reason why the $p$-adic integers so terrible to work in is the fact that $\zeta$ *doesn't* exist in $\mathbf{Z}_p$. That is, $L=\mathbf{Z}_p(x^{1/p}, \zeta)$. Note that any ring homomorphism $\varphi:L\to M$ is completely determined by the images $\varphi(x^{1/p})$ and $\varphi(\zeta)$. Such maps exist with the provision that $\varphi(x^{1/p})\ne 0$ and $\varphi(\zeta)$ is be a primitve $p$th root of unity.

To show $f$ is irreducible, it suffices to show that the Galois group $G(L/k)$ acts transitively on the roots of $f(z)$, meaning that for any roots $\alpha, \alpha'$, we can always find an automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ fixing $K$ and sending $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha'$.

(If you don't know Galois theory, the intuition here is that invertible homomorphisms $\sigma:L\to L$ that fix $k$ will fix the coefficients of polynomials $q(z)$ in $k[z]$. Hence, if $\sigma\circ q = q\circ \sigma$, so if $\alpha$ is a root of $q$, then so is $\sigma(\alpha)$. In particular, we know that $f$ has no double roots, so if we could break up $f(z)=q(z)r(z)$, then we would not be able to send any of the roots of $q$ to any of the roots of $r$.)

So pick two roots of $f(z)$, say, $\zeta^jx^{1/p}$ and $\zeta^k x^{1/p}$. Let $\sigma$ be the homomorphism determined by $\sigma(x^{1/p})=\zeta^{k-j}x^{1/p}$, $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta$. Then $\sigma$ is clearly injective and surjective, so it is an automorphism. Furthermore, since $\sigma(x)=x$, $\sigma$ fixes $k$, so it is an automorphism of $L/k$. Finally, $\sigma(\zeta^jx^{1/p}) = \zeta^{k}x^{1/p}$, as desired.

So $G(L/k)$ indeed acts transitively, and thus $f(z)$ is irreducible.

---

**Case 3: You meant the $2$-adics**

Exact same thing again, but $\zeta \in k$ just like in case 1. Not that there was actually any difference at all between the cases.

Comment: Thank you! I mean $ \mathbb{Z}_p $ the field $ \mathbb{F}_p $.